# Change screen resolution form 1366*768 to 1024*600 in windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, display, resolution

I was trying to lower my screen resolution to 1024*600, but the slider doesn't go as far. Is there anyway to lower it manually? Maybe a registry entry?

Comment: Which graphics driver are you using?

Comment: Do you mean 1024x768?

Comment: I'm using an Intel HD 4000 graphics card with driver version 10.18.10.4061. And no, I mean 1024*600.

Comment: @theGuy 1024x600 might not be a supported resolution for your notebook. You could try using [Intel's graphics control panel to set a custom resolution](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-029478.htm). However, this could damage your display device. As Intel puts it, "Altering modes may reduce system stability and useful life of the system and chipset, cause the chipset and other system components to fail, cause reductions in computer performance, cause additional heat or other damage, and affect system data integrity"